# What is the Amazon EC2 equivalent of the AppEngine Channel API?

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, comet, channel-api

If any.  I. e. if there is something that is only roughly similar, I would appreciate if you could characterize what are the limitations and differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SNS does not seem to be the right solution. The right solution is, or would be if it doesn't yet support it, for SQS to provide an HTTP API to pick objects off a queue.

Answer (score 5):

I think the closest you get is [Amazon's Simple Notification Service](http://aws.amazon.com/sns/) which offers some of the same characteristics of Google AppEngine's Channel API. The big minus here is the lack of JavaScript library to utilize this from a browser. Someone [asked](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=252448&#252448) about JavaScript support, but didn't get an answer.

One other option would be to deploy a server with [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) and/or [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) support like [Glassfish](http://antwerkz.com/glassfish-ose-3-1-is-out-with-websocket-support-included/). You will not get infrastructure provided by Amazon, but still is a viable solution.

Comment: are you sure you can access Simple Notification Service from a browser? i can write my own javascript so i don't need a library but i am not sure if i can access Simple Notification Service from a browser.

Comment: You seem to be correct: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=203178&#203178

You can still add a small serverside part which receives the messages and sends it to SNS and also have a serverside for returning messages to the clients, but then you probably must have a WebSocket/Comet server deployed.

Comment: @agksmehx You could also use an alternative web service that specifically does this form of messaging and has a JavaScript client. A couple good examples are: http://beaconpush.com/ and http://www.pubnub.com/

Comment: @Bryce, thanks - i had found APE: http://www.ape-project.org/ (will compare to your suggestions)